# Not-accepted questions - do you have any?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

It came up in the chat today when @uncovery pointed out that many experienced members of the site hadn't accepted some of his answers (not maliciously or anything, it was just observed).

I myself had quite a few I'd not gotten around to accepting, and have just tidied up some, when @Dirty-flow kindly made a little [query](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ano+hasaccepted%3Ano) to show that we have <strike>1589</strike> 7,767 non-closed, non-accepted questions.

Obviously **not every question needs accepting if you're not happy with the answers that have come through so far** - I'm still waiting on a [decent source of Kopi Luwak in Melbourne](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/18381/101) but maybe we can all have a look through and check if we have some we can accept :)

Comment: The ratio of `not accepted` / `all not closed` is about 30%, pretty similar to the one of older and larger TeX.SX site, so it's not something to worry about much. Still, it's better to accept an answer if there's is a one which is worth it! :)

Comment: @tohecz yeah it wasn't a big concern, just something that uncovery had pointed out and certainly I could find a few of mine that were ready for accept. It's just a little reminder to check our questions, I guess :)

Comment: If you want to find your own non-accepted questions, add `user:me` to the query made by Dirty-flow.

Comment: I have this one, but I have no answers on it to accept :-( http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/1128/1381

Comment: @RoryAlsop Same for this question: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/not-accepted-questions-do-you-have-any

Comment: Bernhard - did you mean to link to this very question?

Comment: Oh, thanks pnuts. That is a good answer (even if it isn't what I wanted :-/

Comment: I have no idea what you are getting at. Bernhard has linked to this question, which has no answers.

Answer (score 1):

> Not-accepted questions - do you have any?

Yes, these on main for example:

[Do I have to fill out a form when submitting a blood test for a Kurdistan residency permit? If so, what details does it request?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42668/do-i-have-to-fill-out-a-form-when-submitting-a-blood-test-for-a-kurdistan-reside)

[Supplying your own needle for Blood test for a Kurdistan residency permit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42666/supplying-your-own-needle-for-blood-test-for-a-kurdistan-residency-permit)

[Where can I apply for Kurdistan short-term residency?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42657/where-can-i-apply-for-kurdistan-short-term-residency)

[Minimum available passport blank page requirements](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37127/minimum-available-passport-blank-page-requirements)

For the first there is no A yet for me to consider Accepting ([see](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4197/4995)).

For the second (needle) I have Commented on the A. I searched for the video mentioned without success. There is a time element so an A that is not even direct and could be as much as 22 years old concerning a relatively fluid environment does not (yet?) merit a tick, IMO. I have though upvoted it.

For the third (residency permit) I think the A is to a different Q, not what was asked, as I have Commented there.

For the fourth (blank pages) I very much appreciate your A and have upvoted and Commented on it. However I am still hoping for more and you seem to accept your A is far from comprehensive (with good reason!). I am usually in favour of applying a tick to the best of very helpful As regardless of whether comprehensive or tested by me (on the basis that even if not *the* result good indication of the direction towards and distance to such a result may be adequate) but at the moment I am just short of deeming your answer 'one that worked for me'.

However, I think your main interest may not be in what any one user's acceptance rate is but rather concern, in my view fully justified, that where the system is not used the way it was designed to the outcome will not be what it could and should be. As it happens, that is a ['pet peeve'](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3957/4995) of mine.